# Looking For A .Net Table Component

Tags: .net, controls

I'm looking for a table control (aka ListView or DataGridView) that:

- Can display a series of rows as a "child" of a row - if anyone's spent any time with Access, it does this when it works out associations between rows
- will let me insert headers into the middle of the table, so I can e.g. group by a particular row and have a header above each group.
- Ideally, let me draw more than one table at once, but I can fake this with a Panel and two table controls so I'm not so bothered.

It'd be nice if it could reach the efficiency of a DataGridView - my data tables generally have a lot of rows that tend to go in all at once, and paging is not really desired in this application.

Essentially, I'm looking for a table control where I can break the table at any row and stick something else in.

Is anyone aware of something that might be suitable?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [obout](http://www.obout.com/grid/) grid can do what you're asking for.
There are also other third party vendors like [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx), [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/aspnet/webgrid.aspx) and [ComponentOne](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/WebGridASPNET/) that all have grid controls that should do what you want. I'd recommend downloading the trial versions of each and seeing which one works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

I promise I am in no way affiliated with [DevExpress](http://devexpress.com/), however, having used [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx), [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/aspnet/webgrid.aspx) and [DevExpress](http://devexpress.com/), if you are looking for a 3rd party control, in my experience, the DevExpress controls are by far my favourite in usability, functionality and look and feel. I have not used [ComponentOne](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/WebGridASPNET/), as mentioned above, so I cannot comment on them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually on the other side of that one, I've used all three in various pursuits and freelance gigs and have found the [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com) controls a bit more versatile and seem to offer a bit more with their .Net 3.5 support.  What do you like about the [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com) ones more... i.e., why should I revisit them the next time one of my jobs is looking for that type of UI control suite?

Answer (score 0):

You can try my Grid, it's completely and can be found at [www.webgrid.com](http://www.webgrid.com).

It should meet your requirements, and the syntax is similar to GridView.

Hope it works for you.